# Differentiate $\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$ with respect to $y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I want to differentiate this, with respect to $y$:

$\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$

I try to derivate with the product rule as:

$(-y(x^2+y^2)^{-1})'_y$ => $-(x^2+y^2)^{-1} + 2y^2(x^2+y^2)^{-2}$

However this is not correct, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is perfectly correct, but not simplified. Reduce to the same denominator.

Comment: I must have made a mistake when plugging my expression and the correct expression into wolframalpha to see if they are equal. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hint: we get $$\frac{-(x^2+y^2)+y\cdot 2y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ by the Quotient rule.